# Launch XCode UI test with URL launch option

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode-ui-testing

I'd like to write a test for my iOS app that verifies the correct screen content is shown when the app is launched from a custom registered URL scheme.

For example, a user receives an email with a link to `myapp://action1/1234`. When they tap on this link, my app is launched and the screen displays "1234".

In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` my AppDelegate checks to see if `launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey]` exists and takes appropriate action.

How do I write a UI test so that the app launchOptions dictionary contains the expected URL when the app is launched?

Comment: A bit late and just a link but this is what you want I think: https://aross.se/2018/06/17/ios-ui-tests-for-custom-url-scheme.html

Answer (score 1):

You can make this work by leveraging `launchEnvironment` on `XCUIApplication` in combination with a few lines of custom code in your target app. Basically you would set a custom launch environment variable for this test, and in your app you would check for that variable and handle it the same way you would handle the existence of the particular `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsURLKey` you're expecting.

In your app you can check that value via `NSProcessInfo.processInfo.environment` which returns a dictionary of the environment variables.

(Take note that the default **XCTestCase** template in Xcode 7 includes a call to `XCUIApplication -launch` in `setup` which will terminate any previously running instance, and launch a new instance by default.)

*Edit: wanted to add, I've written a little bit more about this in an article on [Xcode 7 UI Testing Tips](http://sound-of-silence.com/?article=20160215), in case it's helpful.*